# Table of Symmetric Function

Tags: function-construction

I have a function of the type `F[x][y][z] == F[x][z][y] == F[-x][-y][-z]`. I'm making a table of every possible value, as in

```
Table[F[i][j][k], {i,{±1,±2,±3}, {j,{±1,±2,±3}, {k,{±1,±2,±3}].
```

The function itself takes a considerable amount of time to compute. Is there any way for me to take advantage of these symmetries? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using memoization in the definition of the function?

```
F[x_, y_, z_] := F[x, y, z] = F[x, z, y] = F[-x, -y, -z] = _;
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also write a modified function that takes into account the expected symmetries. Consider for instance this toy example of a slow function:

```
f1[x_][y_][z_] := (Pause[1/9]; (y z + x (y + z))/(1 - x y - x z - y z + x y z (x + y + z)))

AbsoluteTiming[r1 = Table[f1[i][j][k], {i, {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}},
                          {j, {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}}, {k, {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}}];]
   {24.4644, Null}
```

Then here is a version that exploits known symmetries:

```
f2[x_][y_][z_] := Which[! OrderedQ[{y, z}], f1[x][z][y], 
                        VectorQ[{x, y, z}, Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ], f1[-x][-y][-z], 
                        True, f1[x][y][z]]
```

This version evaluates a little faster:

```
AbsoluteTiming[r2 = Table[f2[i][j][k], {i, {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}},
                          {j, {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}}, {k, {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}}];]
   {24.4358, Null}

r1 === r2
   True
```